# Next.js Image component not showing image and yarn dev server quitting with error

Tags: image, next.js

I am trying to render an illustration with the following path `/public/illustrations/free_mode.jpg`, but for some reason when I navigate to the page where the image is supposed to be rendered the image is not found and yarn dev command exit with code 137. When I checked `.next` folder I've found all the other images in the cache except for the one causing the error. My code is the following:

```js
<Image
    src="/illustrations/free_mode.jpg"
    alt="illustration"
    width={300} height={300}
    className="w-full h-9 md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg"
/>
```

It worked well for other images but when I added this one it doesn't the app server crashed.

Comment: module.exports = {
  images: {
    formats: ['image/webp'],
  },
}

Do you have this in the config?

Comment: I added those but it seems that this image is causing the problem, I tried other images and it worked fine but this one causes the error.

Comment: Try removing that _ from the image and see it that works

Comment: Can you access the `/illustrations/free_mode.jpg` image directly from the browser? Can you show us the error you're getting?

Comment: It is now working fine, turns out that my pc was running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

To use a local image, import your .jpg, .png, or .webp files:

```
import freeMode from './illustrations/free_mode.jpg'

<Image
    src={freeMode}
    alt="illustration"
    width={300} height={300}
    className="w-full h-9 md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg"
/>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I have tried it this way and it didn't help